# How could I make a calendar?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a calendar for a client's website. I was wondering how should I go about doing this. I want it to when someone taps on a day it would show a modal with a form for that day. This form would then submit a scheduled appointment for that day. I assume I could use JavaScript or PHP to change the days for the appropriate month and year.

A good example of this is in windows 10 you have a calendar that lets you click on a day and you can set up an agenda or something. If anyone could point me in the direction of how I could start this please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: There are tons of examples on the internet, just google. We're here to help with specific programming problems, not to do some research for you.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript date object is pretty handy. You can do something like this to get current dates of the current month:

```
const today = new Date()
const date = new Date()
date.setDate(1)
var calendar = ''
for(var i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
  if(date.getMonth() == today.getMonth()) {
    calendar += `<div onclick="openModal()">${date.getDate()}</div> `
  }
}
```

This is just a small piece of code to point you to the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I find this could be useful for making the calendar's buttons the right numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="date">
```

HTML5 input type will give a calendar by default